# How to close menu bar in Adobe XD?

Tags: android, adobe-xd

I'm new to Adobe XD. I created a side menu and whenever I click on it, it opens the menu, but I have to choose one of the options there and I can't click on the right side of the screen to close the menu. How can I make Adobe XD close the menu and stay in the same screen?

Example:

[image]

I want to be able to click on the right part of the screen (the white part) and close the menu, but it only allows to click one of the menu options.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the **Overlay** Action Type. Here's how:

1. Create an artboard the same size as your menu and move your menu to it
2. On your main artboard, create a shape that will open the menu when clicked
3. Switch to Prototype Mode
4. Draw a link from the shape you created in step #2 to the artboard you created in step #1
5. With your link still selected (solid blue line between the shape and menu artboard), change the Action Type option on the right sidebar to **Overlay**
6. If done correctly, you should be able to Play your Prototype (CTRL+ENTER or CMD+ENTER on Mac), click your shape, and the menu should appear on screen. You should then be able to click anywhere **outside** of the menu to close it.